# Play! framework - backward compatibility

Tags: java, web, playframework, playframework-2.0, backwards-compatibility

I'm currently developing a new website powered by Play! framework 2.0 and I have two questions:

1. is there going to be a newer version in the near future?
2. if the answer to the above is "yes", is there going to be a backward compatibility?

Comment: The best place to find this information is not here, but the Play! Framework site/forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Branch 2.x is current, newest stable version and there are no plans for new one.

You can use it, and I think that it will take at least long years for next revolutionary edition.

Comment: hey! the project is built on 2.1.2. if i use 2.4.0 will it be a problem?

Comment: @CodeShadow You can adopt it as it's still 2.x branch, anyway you need to go step by step between "Migration guide" docs, there are little changes between each 2.x (i.e. moved/renamed packages, etc) , you'll finde them here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Home

Comment: I find some upgrades in version rather difficult. For example between 2.4 and 2.5, so much has changed! The amount of rework to be done in large scale Enterprise Applications for an upgrade is honestly, annoying.